# Verifying CRT used in library (.lib)

Tags: c++, windows, crt

How do I check what runtime library a static library (.lib) in Windows has linked to?

I'm compiling my project with /MDd and I presume a library I'm linking to is using /MTd Multi-threaded Debug

```
Error   7   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)    C:\...\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
```

LIBCPMTD.LIB = Multithreaded, static link

I know there's an option `/NODEFAULTLIB:"libcpmtd.lib"` which I've tried and succeeded with, but I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix this doing the following

```
> dumpbin /DIRECTIVES C:\..\ThirdParty\tidy\windows\lib\libtidy
.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\..\ThirdParty\tidy\windows\lib\libtidy.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT"
   /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES"
...
```

It's cleary linking to MT.  I recompiled the lib using /MDd and it linked fine.

Comment: That's cool, but if I have "MSVCRT" for /MD, how do I find a particular version of Visual Studio used? I.e. which MSVCRTxx.dll is referenced?

Answer (score 0):

Since [MSVPRTD.LIB is the importlib of the *dynamic* link library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) of the crt, while you explicitely asked to link to the crt *statically*, **something seems wrong with your build chain**.

You may want to check the project file visually for contradictions.

Comment: The project I'm trying to compile is using /MDd which is the correct setting.  Something I'm trying to link to is using /MT(d) static or what not.  How does Visual Studio 2010 help in detecting which of the library I link to has a conflicting CRT?  Is there no option to manually inspecting all the project files?